# How can I get messages between two message in Discord.JS

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am trying to delete the messages between two messages. How can I get all of the messages between that two messages?

I'm stuck here

```
    if (subcommand === "between") {
    if (!args[1] || !args[2]) {
        return;
    }

    let id_first = args[1];
    let id_last = args[2];
```

Comment: You would need to fetch the last X messages, find both messages within the collection, then splice the collection accordingly

Comment: I don't know how fetch works. I'm fetching the id_first and I can get the message content of id_first but, how can I get all of the messages between id_first and id_last?

Comment: You can view the docs for fetching X amount of messages [Here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageManager?scrollTo=fetch)

Comment: I don't have a specified amount of messages, I have two message IDs and trying to get message count between those.

Comment: You can't fetch a message inbetween without fetching all the messages around it. You'll have to work with the entire message collection, there is no method to find an "inbetween message"